# How can I use ruby gem commands like bundler when ruby is installed by nix package manager?

Tags: ruby, nix, gem

I'm new to nix package manager.

After installing nix into Ubuntu 16.04 LTS(Japanese translated version), I installed ruby with `nix-env` command. Then I did `gem install bundler`. That seemed to work fine.

However I couldn't use `bundle` command, while `require 'bundler'` in IRB session seemed to work fine. That made me confused.

From my understanding, in general, it is no need to do anything for using `bundle` command after `gem install bundler`

How should I understand this problem and how can I solve it?

P.S English is not my native language; please excuse typing, grammar or/and word selecting errors.

```
$ nix-env -q
nix-1.11.9
ruby-2.4.1

$ gem install bundler
Fetching: bundler-1.15.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.15.0
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.15.0
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.15.0
Done installing documentation for bundler after 6 seconds
1 gem installed

$ bundle init
プログラム 'bundle' はまだインストールされていません。 次のように入力することでインストールできます:
sudo apt install ruby-bundler

$ irb
require 'bundler'
=> true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try: nix-shell -p ruby bundler

and have a look at:
https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/nixos/modules/services/misc/gitlab.nix